At long wavelengths, any time evolution is of order the Hubble time $\mathcal{H}^{-1}$?
I encountered the claim indicated in the title in a physics paper, where they gave no further context or explanation, and I would like to be able to understand it and prove it, but I don't know how to proceed.
I know that the Hubble time is defined as $\mathcal{H}=\dot{a}/a$ where $\dot{a}=da/d\eta$ is the derivative of the scale factor $a$ with respect to conformal time $\eta$. Therefore, $\mathcal{H}$ has, indeed, units of time.
Any suggestions or explanations of what is being stated here?
